# $f(x)=a^{x}.$ Find $f(f^{-1}(x))$. Explain the intuition behind this.

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Question: $f(x)=a^{x}.$ Find $f(f^{-1}(x))$. Explain the 
intuition behind this.

I know that $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$, so it is a silly question, but what does 
it really mean? How would you explain it from basics to a student in for 
example middle school?

Comment: Would this middle schooler know about logarithms?

Comment: What is $ff^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: @JavaMan, that is composition of f and its inverse.

Comment: I'd find it a bit easier to work with $f^{-1}f (x)$ instead. Imagine you take a (continuous, injective) function, like $f(x)=a^x$. What does function mapping represent? It takes every value $x$ in the real line, and lifts it to a value $a^x$. Then $f^{-1}$ is precisely the undo move on this function. So you take a value in $a^x$, and project it down to its real line counterpart. So you lift then project, so trivially it's just going to be the identity. Now it is clear that you can do the opposite, taking elements in the curve $a^x$, projecting them, then lifting them back, hence $ff^{-1}(x)=x$

Comment: @SeanRoberson, assume they have covered logs.